# How to npm audit global packages

Tags: npm

As stated in the official [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/running-a-security-audit#running-a-security-audit-with-npm-audit) you can manually run `npm audit` on locally installed packages, which must have both **package.json** and **package-lock.json** files.

Globally installed packages doesn't have **package-lock.json**, if you run an audit it will trow an error: `npm ERR! code EAUDITNOLOCK`

How can I run `npm audit` on all globally installed packages?

Comment: you can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-global-audit

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**It's good to keep them up-to-date.**

*That's not really auditing*, but with few as possible global packages, this should be fine enough.

there is [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) or alternatively [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check)

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

check outdated global packages:

```
ncu -g
```

**OR**

as recommended by @pldg via npx

```
npx npm-check-updates -g
```

**OR**

as recommended by @wheredidthatnamecomefrom

```
npx npm-global-audit
```

this is a script running with yarn. it does a temporary copy of your current global packages. see more on their [github](https://github.com/andrewbrey/npm-global-audit).

**this the npm way** as recommended by @Henke

```
npx npm-global-audit --auditor npm
```

Comment: Thanks it works. If you don't want to install npm-check-updates you can use [npx](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx): `npx npm-check-updates -g`

Comment: npm-global-audit will do a true audit.

Comment: [`npx npm-global-audit --auditor npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-global-audit) if you don't use yarn.

Comment: Why it is required to install more deps. into the project instead of considering a solution for the current problem?

Comment: @FrancoGil you are right. this is not the most correct answer, but has a green checkmark at it. pls check the answer of `philn5d` which seems to be a valid solution without extra needed packages. in the end it's about what comes in more handy for some devs, i would say. other then that you could open up a new question, as i did now not answered yours here.

Answer (score 12):

I found an answer to your question:

1. go to your global npm folder (e.g. `cd $(npm root -g)/..`).
2. `npm init` just keep pressing enter to the questions, or `npm init -y` so it is populated with default values. That'll give you a package.json that npm audit needs and automatically add what's in your node_modules to it.
3. `npm i --package-lock-only` will install if needed and add package-lock.json (required by npm audit).
4. run `npm audit`.

To find your global npm folder just run `npm root -g` it'll print it out at the end. The `package.json` file needs to be in its parent folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, anyway I don't think it's a good solution. I can instead list all my global installed packages, install them in a local repository and then `npm audit`. My question is: how can I run an audit directly on global installed packages? Maybe is not possibile...

Comment: This gets you to a state where you can run audit directly on your globally installed packages. But, I suppose the packages.json wouldn't get updated when you install new packages globally. You could always delete the package.json + package-lock.json and repeat whenever you want to audit again. Easy enough to make into a script.

Comment: The only thing that worries me is to messing around with npm folder. Maybe it's better to create a local repository and make a script to mirror the global packages to that repository in which audit run automatically

Comment: That's an interesting idea too! You'd have to perform the updates individually, even if they could be done by `npm audit`.

Comment: @philn5d You say "easy enough to make into a script" but being web devs, some of us only made websites, never "scripts". Do you know any good recourses or guides to get started on our very first script ?

Comment: this is the correct answer, thanks Phil (and Benjamin)

Comment: Thank you. Simple solution. Just remember not to go all the way into /node_modules/npm as I did at first I just copied whatever npm printed out. Only take the first part. In my case C:\Program Files\npm

Answer (score 6):

```sh
# Without installing the package locally, using npx
npx npm-check-updates -g

# otherwise, install and update on occasion 
npm install -g npm-check-updates

# Then check outdated global packages:
ncu -g
```

Comment: [ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is another interesting way to audit global packages without using some third party packages. After all, we don't want to violate security principles by using them on such a sensitive data ;).

You might need to run terminal (`bash` or similar on Unix-like system or `cmd` on Windows) with administrative priviledges to get proper results.

1. Use this command to figure out the path and the list of globally installed packages:

```
npm i
```

You should get something like this:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs -> .\
├── gulp-cli@2.3.0
├── nodemon@2.0.15
├── npm@8.4.1
└── ts-node@10.5.0
```

2. Go to that path using your terminal. Keep in mind that this path might by a link (or symlink) to another folder.
3. Create a `package.json` file in that folder with the contents reflecting global packages list and exact versions you've got in step 1 like this:

```json
{
  "name": "-",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-cli": "2.3.0",
    "nodemon": "2.0.15",
    "npm": "8.4.1",
    "ts-node": "10.5.0"
  }
}
```

Pay attention that npm itself is included as well.

4. Create a `package-lock.json` file there using this cli command:

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

5. Run audit with

```
npm audit
```

It worked for me on my Windows 8.1 system at least, running node v.16.13.2, npm v.8.4.1.

Interesting that I've got a moderate severity vulnerability for npm itself in my report.

I would appreciate it if you'll share your experience with the way I suggested to solve the problem.

Comment: doesn't work the same for me npm version 8.9.0 on Linux.Tries to read the current directories package.json meaning its not a global search.